# Python tkinter, Making two text widget's scrolling synchronize

Tags: python, text, scroll, tkinter

I am trying to make two text widget's scrolling synchronize. So far I've achieved that using an Scrollbar, when using the scrollbar it works fine. But for example, when I have the focus on one of the text widgets and I use the mousewheel to scroll, only the text widget with the focus is scrolled, the scrollbar is also updated but the other text remains the same. The same behaviour occurs when using page down or page up keys and as fas as I know for every form of scrolling that doesn't use the scrollbar.

This is my code, I think only **init** is the relevant part where I bind the events, but just in case I decided to put all my code:

```
## HexText class
#
#
class HexText (tkk.Frame):

    __POS_TEXT = "00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F"
    __OFFSET_TEXT = "0x00000000"
    __LINE_LENGTH = len(__POS_TEXT)

    def __init__(self, master):

        super(HexText, self).__init__(master)

        self.__create_widgets()
        self.__organize_widgets()

    def __scrolls(self, *args):
        self.__data.yview(*args)
        self.__offset.yview(*args)

    def __create_widgets(self):

        self.__scrollbar = tkk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.__scrollbar["orient"] = tk.VERTICAL
        self.__scrollbar["command"] = self.__scrolls

        self.__data = tk.Text(self)
        self.__data["height"] = 8
        self.__data["width"] = HexText.__LINE_LENGTH
        self.__data["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        self.__data["relief"] = tk.GROOVE
        self.__data["yscrollcommand"] = self.__scrollbar.set

        self.__offset = tk.Text(self)
        self.__offset["height"] = 8
        self.__offset["width"] = len(HexText.__OFFSET_TEXT)
        self.__offset["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        self.__offset["relief"] = tk.FLAT
        self.__offset["bg"] = self.winfo_toplevel()["bg"]
        self.__offset["yscrollcommand"] = self.__scrollbar.set

        self.__pos = tk.Text(self)
        self.__pos.insert(tk.CURRENT, HexText.__POS_TEXT)
        self.__pos["height"] = 1
        self.__pos["width"] = HexText.__LINE_LENGTH
        self.__pos["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        self.__pos["relief"] = tk.FLAT
        self.__pos["bg"] = self.winfo_toplevel()["bg"]

    def __organize_widgets(self):

        self.__pos.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)
        self.__offset.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)
        self.__data.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)
        self.__scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)

    @staticmethod
    def __get_char_index(string):
        i = str.find(string, '.')

        if i >= 0:
            i = int(string[i+1:])
        else:
            raise ValueError

        return i

    @staticmethod
    def __get_line_index(string):
        i = str.find(string, '.')

        if i >= 0:
            i = int(string[:i])
        else:
            raise ValueError

        return i

    @staticmethod
    def __get_hex_value(string):

        if (len(string) != 1):
            raise ValueError

        i = "%02X" % ord(string)

        return i

    def __update_offset(self, line_index):

        i = "0x%08X\n" % ((line_index) * 0x10)
        self.__offset["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.__offset.insert(tk.CURRENT, i)
        self.__offset["state"] = tk.DISABLED

    def __append(self, string):
        self.__data["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.__data.insert(tk.CURRENT, string)
        self.__data["state"] = tk.DISABLED

    def __write_char(self, string):
        str_index = self.__data.index(tk.CURRENT)
        i = HexText.__get_char_index(str_index)

        if (len(string) != 1):
            raise ValueError

        if (i == 0):
            self.__update_offset(HexText.__get_line_index(str_index) - 1)

        if (i == HexText.__LINE_LENGTH - 2):
            self.__append(HexText.__get_hex_value(string) + '\n')
        else:
            self.__append(HexText.__get_hex_value(string) + ' ')

    def write_str(self, string):

        for chars in string:
            self.__write_char(chars)
```

This is an image of the widget I'm trying to create, a simple hex viewer (both text widgets have the same amount of lines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb8IH.png

So my question is, should I handle all the page up, page down, mousewheel and every other form of scrolling independently? Isn't there a more simple way of having both text widgets have the same scrolling all the time?

Comment: Added some stuff and corrected mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question if the event handling should be done independently for each scrollbar - that is a decision you have to make.
If you want to only make this widget for this purpose, you can handle both together not on their own. Create a custom event handler for that and call the setters/getters accordingly.

If you have the two widgets (including the two scrollbars) are in a main widget where you want to have the events bound, bind them over there using 
`widget.bind(<EVENT>, handler)`or using `widget.bind_all(<EVENT>, handler)` to bind also the events raised from child widgets to these handlers.

As you are already using the same handler (`self.__scrollbar.set`) in your code, you could just use a custom event handler to bind `Page Up` / `Page Down` keys to scroll by a specific offset, and one custom to scroll by `MouseWheel`- Event.

If you scroll independently and call both scrolling functions at these handlers or if you scroll both in one function is up to you, as mentioned above.

As the scrolling needs to be called for each `tk.Text`-Widget I personally prefer calling both scrollings in one handler bound to the parent widget and all below (so using `bind_all`), but that is a matter of personal preference I think.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a bit old but this solution works perfectly. The Text widgets react to rolling the mouse wheel by default so there's no need to bind anything.

```
import sys
if sys.version[0] < '3':
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *


class ScrolledTextPair(Frame):
    '''Two Text widgets and a Scrollbar in a Frame'''

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # no need for super

        # Different default width
        if 'width' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['width'] = 30

        # Creating the widgets
        self.left = Text(self, **kwargs)
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.right = Text(self, **kwargs)
        self.right.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Changing the settings to make the scrolling work
        self.scrollbar['command'] = self.on_scrollbar
        self.left['yscrollcommand'] = self.on_textscroll
        self.right['yscrollcommand'] = self.on_textscroll

    def on_scrollbar(self, *args):
        '''Scrolls both text widgets when the scrollbar is moved'''
        self.left.yview(*args)
        self.right.yview(*args)

    def on_textscroll(self, *args):
        '''Moves the scrollbar and scrolls text widgets when the mousewheel
        is moved on a text widget'''
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)
        self.on_scrollbar('moveto', args[0])


# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    t = ScrolledTextPair(root, bg='white', fg='black')
    t.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    for i in range(50):
        t.left.insert(END,"foo %s\n" % i)
        t.right.insert(END,"bar %s\n" % i)

    root.title("Text scrolling example")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very cool. But the behaviour is a bit weird when the amount of text in each is not the same.