# How to scroll two parallel text widgets with one scrollbar?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to scroll a "line number" text widget and a "code" text widget simultaneously in an IDE I'm developing. How would I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried having the scrollbar call a function that calls the `yview` method of your two widgets?

Comment: @BryanOakley - I have set the scrollbar the scroll the "code" widgets using `self.vsb=tk.Scrollbar(self,command=self.text.yview)` . But I do not see how I can set the same for `self.numb` (the line number widget) without removing the scroll on `self.text` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED] It's really easy to do this in Tcl, so I figured it had to be possible to get a Tkinter equivalent of the following Tcl procedure:

```
proc rollon {boxes args} {
    foreach box $boxes {
        eval {$box yview} $args
     }
}
```

After a few failed efforts, I came up with this, which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
def viewall(*args):
    global tx, tx2
    eval('tx.yview(*args)')
    eval('tx2.yview(*args)')
tx = Text(root, background='white', width = '20', height = '8')
tx2 = Text(root, background='white', width = '20', height = '8')
rolly = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=viewall)
tx['yscrollcommand'] = rolly.set
tx2['yscrollcommand'] = rolly.set
tx.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
tx2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
rolly.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.mainloop()
```

Somebody who knows more Python than I do could probably figure out how to do this without listing the "yview" for each text widget separately, but this should get you going.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval`. Just call `tx.yview(*args)`.

Comment: True. And since the occasions to use a huge number of multi-scrolling widgets will probably be very few, it may not be worth the effort of trying to find out how not to list each "yview" separately. For only two widgets, it wouldn't be worth more than the few seconds it takes to read this comment. :o)

Answer (score 1):

My own solution, while not the best, was this: (Forgive the lack of context)

```
def scroller(self,*args):#Move me
    self.text.yview(*args)
    self.numb.yview(*args)
def on_textscroll(self, *args):#Move me
    self.vsb.set(*args)
    self.scroller('moveto', args[0])
```

Comment: A full example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038701/python-tkinter-making-two-text-widgets-scrolling-synchronize/35824343#35824343