# How to connect multiple text to one scrollbar with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, scrollbar

Im coding my personal text editor. But i have a problem with the 2 widget text and the scrollbar (connect one scrollbar to two text).

***What is my idea and logic (at the beginning)?***

I want to display 2 text, one for writing text entered by user, and one to display the number of the line. I pack both of them, in the root. Then i create a scrollbar, that will scroll on Y axes the 2 text, so what i want to do (mainly) is to connect 2 widget (text) to one scrollbar.

***But it didn't work.***

This system absolutely doesn't work, are there any suggest or fix to fix this first idea?

***Other ideas that i found.***

After the first attempt, i thought that i can pack the 2 texts into 1 container. I tried to create a frame (packed into root) that contains the 2 texts, i did this because i have to connect the scrollbar only to the frame. But it didn't work, moreover it didnt allow me to write the following snippet: `command=frame.yview` in the scrollbar option, it seems that i cant connect frame to scrollbar.

***So:***

I will ask u if my reasoning are good, and how to solve. If not what can i do?

***Similar question found on Google:*** (but that i dont undestand)

[How to scroll two parallel text widgets with one scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957671/how-to-scroll-two-parallel-text-widgets-with-one-scrollbar)

[Tkinter adding line number to text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget)

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.geometry("480x540+100+100")
root.config(cursor='')

line = Text(root, bg="light grey", font="Roman 24", width=4)
line.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

text = Text(root, bg="grey", font="Roman 24")
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text, orient=VERTICAL, command=(line.yview, text.yview))
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
line.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

for n in range(50):
    line.insert("{}.0".format(n+1), "{}\n".format(n+1))
    text.insert("{}.0".format(n+1), "Line no. {}\n".format(n+1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about a scrollbar - it just calls a function when you move it. The API for this function is well defined. While it normally should call the `yview` (or `xview`) method of a scrollable window, there's no requirement that it must.

If you want to control two widgets with a single scrollbar, create a function for your scrollbar that scrolls both windows.

```
def multiple_yview(*args):
    line.yview(*args)
    text.yview(*args)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(text, orient=VERTICAL, command=multiple_yview)
```

You will have a similar problem when you scroll the text widget while entering new lines or moving around with cursor keys. You'll need to configure the `yscrollcommand` attribute of the text widget to call a function so that it both updates the scrollbar and also scrolls the other window (and maybe also add additional line numbers)

Comment: Ok, but with your code i have just solved the problem with scrollbar, but theres another problem. If i scroll up/down texts with scrollbar all ok, but if i use mouse wheel it doesnt work. What should i do?

Comment: This is a different problem, ask a new question for it Riccardo.