# tkinter - text not expanding inside the frame of a canvas

Tags: text, tkinter, frame

[image]
**Issue:**
As you can see on the image, the `text_field` and `can_frame` (frame inside the canvas) is not filling out the purple void.

**How my application is constructed:**
I got a `right_frame`(purple) and `left_frame`(pink) in my root window. in the `right_frame` have I placed a `canvas` in which I have placed a frame that I call `can_frame`. 
Now in that `can_frame` I placed two `text_fields` .

The problem is, how do I make the `can_frame` as well as the `text_fields` (in the `can_frame`) fill the purple space.

**Full code of a new simple application I made:**

```
class Analyse_Window:
    def __init__(self, root):

        root.grid_rowconfigure   (0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


        self.left_frame = Frame( root, bg='pink',       height=580, width=450)
        self.right_frame = Frame(root, bg='light blue', height=580, width=450)
        self.left_frame.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.right_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.right_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create and setup canvas, scrollbar, and right frame with text fields.
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.right_frame, borderwidth=10, bg='purple')
        self.can_frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='yellow')


        self.scrollbar  = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='vertical',  command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='horizontal',command=self.canvas.xview, width=25)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar2.set)



        # Grid canvas, frame, and scrollbars
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.scrollbar2.grid(row=1, sticky='ew')
        self.canvas.grid(   row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.can_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
        self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)


        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.can_frame, anchor='sw', tags="self.frame")
        self.can_frame.bind( "<Configure>",  self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.foo)




        # Create text fields and put them in the canvas frame
        inp = Text(self.can_frame, width=40, relief='groove')
        inp.insert(END, 'this is a test')
        inp.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        inp.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        inp2 = Text(self.can_frame, width=20, relief='groove')
        inp2.grid(row=2, column=0)


    def foo(self, event):
        w,h = event.width-100, event.height-100
        self.canvas.config(width=w, height=h)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
        # when all widgets are in canvas
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), 'units')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    b = Analyse_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

*You could try to copy paste the code into your own editor and try for yourself?*

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @BryanOakley I hope you are able to help me now, I just updated everything, I even copied the whole script into a new document, and removed all the unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the reason that the canvas is not completely filled is that frames in general fill up the space that their children (text widgets and scrollbars) request. Usually canvas widgets are a poor choice for GUI layouts unless you're displaying drawing elements (lines, ellipses and other shapes). But in your case, all I see are other tk widgets. The layout can be simplified, unless you plan to add drawing elements. So the solution below merely creates a simpler layout of the text widgets with their scrollbars, which I understand *may* not be what you want.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Analyse_Window:
    def __init__(self, root):

        root.grid_rowconfigure   (0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


        self.left_frame = Frame( root, bg='pink',       height=580, width=450)
        self.right_frame = Frame(root, bg='light blue', height=580, width=450)
        self.left_frame.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.right_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.right_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create and setup text widgets with scrollbars
        self.text_top = Text(self.right_frame, relief='groove', wrap='word', width=40)
        self.text_bot = Text(self.right_frame, relief='groove', wrap='word', width=20)
        self.text_top.insert(END, "This is the top text widget")
        self.text_bot.insert(END, "This is the bottom text widget")
        self.text_top['state'] = 'disabled'

        self.sty = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='vertical',  command=self.text_top.yview)
        self.stx = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='horizontal',command=self.text_top.xview, width=25)
        self.text_top.configure(yscrollcommand=self.sty.set, xscrollcommand=self.stx.set)

        self.sby = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='vertical',  command=self.text_bot.yview)
        self.sbx = Scrollbar(self.right_frame, orient='horizontal',command=self.text_bot.xview, width=25)
        self.text_bot.configure(yscrollcommand=self.sby.set, xscrollcommand=self.sbx.set)

        # Grid the text widgets and scrollbars
        self.text_top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
        self.sty.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.stx.grid(row=1, sticky='ew')
        self.text_bot.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nw')
        self.sby.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.sbx.grid(row=3, sticky='ew')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    b = Analyse_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like to scroll through my text widgets all at once, and then only one horizontal scrollbar. And as far as I know, that can only be accomplished by creating a canvas to which you attach the scrollbar to.
 Like shown here: https://gyazo.com/14334a1bb6984c6ba984fc2791a322c6

Comment: You **can** create a [single scrollbar to which 2 or more text widgets will respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038701/python-tkinter-making-two-text-widgets-scrolling-synchronize), if that's really what you want (see the last solution -- #2).